# Show result using Multideminsional Array

Tags: zend-framework, multidimensional-array

I'm working on Question Bank System and i have problems on showing the list of question with the answer from the tables.

[Click to see the table images](http://s13.postimg.org/y3xofslxj/complete.png)

I want to show the result like this:

```
$question = array{
            array {
                'question' => 'Question MCQ',
                'answer'   => array{
                    'answer 1',
                    'answer 2',
                    'answer 3',
                    'answer 4',
                },
                'correct_answer' = 0
            },
            array {
                'question' => 'Question MCA',
                'answer'   => array{
                    'answer 1',
                    'answer 2',
                    'answer 3',
                    'answer 4',
                },
                'correct_answer' = 2
            },
            array {
                'question' => 'Question True and False',
                'answer'   => array{
                    'True',
                    'False',
                },
                'correct_answer' = 1
            },
}
```

The code that im working on right now is this:

1. getQuestionByID()

   ```
   $select = $this->select()
           ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
           ->from(array('q' => $this->_name), array('questionID', 'questionDesc'));

   $query = $select->query();
   $statement = $query->fetchAll();
   return $statement;
   ```
2. getMcQ()

   ```
   $select = $this->select()
           ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
           ->from(array('q' => 'questions'), array('questionID', 'questionDesc'))
           ->join(array('aq' => 'qanswer'), 'q.questionID = aq.questionID')
           ->join(array('a' => 'answers'), 'aq.answerID = a.answerID', array('answerID', 'answerDesc', 'isAnswer'));

   $query = $select->query();
   $stamnt = $query->fetchAll();
   return $stamnt;
   ```
3. Controller

   ```
   $getQ = new Questions();
   $res = $getQ->getQuestionByID();
   $questions = array();

   foreach ($res as $que) {
       $tmp['question'] = $que->questionDesc;

       $res_ans = $getQ->getMcq();
       $index = 0;

       foreach ($res_ans as $ans) {
           $tmp['answer'] = $ans->answerDesc;
           if ($ans->isAnswer == 1) {
               $tmp['correct_answer'] = $index;
           }
           $index++;
       }

       array_push($questions, $tmp);
   }

   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($questions);
   ```
4. The result from my code :
   [click to view result from the code](http://s22.postimg.org/nu1lcqbv5/ans.png)

Any help on this ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand what you want to do with `'correct_answer'` but I think that replacing your controller code by this, it should help you (except maybe the field `'correct_answer'` but the principle will the same for the rest).

```
$getQ    = new Questions();
$res     = $getQ->getQuestionByID();
$res_ans = $getQ->getMcq();

$questions = array();

foreach ($res as $que) {
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp['question'] = $que->questionDesc;
    $index = 0;

    foreach ($res_ans as $ans) {
        if ($ans->questionID == $que->questionID){
            $tmp['answer'][] = $ans->answerDesc;
            if ($ans->isAnswer == 1) {
                $tmp['correct_answer'] = $index;
            }
            $index++;
        }
    }

    array_push($questions, $tmp);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($questions);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Happy for you. :) Can you validate my answer please? :)